# How to solve the Permission Error

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, config, google-code

I have downloaded the [minbill project from google code](http://code.google.com/p/minibill/downloads/detail?name=minibill-20080707.zip&can=2&q=), and tried to run in my wamp server.  But its index.php file says error as,

[image]

The projects **config.php**, has

```
/* Path Information */
//session_save_path:Make sure this is read and writable by the webserver user
$config['session_save_path']    = '/tmp';

//template_cache_dir:Make sure this is read and writable by the webserver user
$config['template_cache_dir']   = '/tmp';
```

**Unchecking is not withstanding in win-7 :**

Another problem is, when I unchecked the Read-only button in Window 7 ultimate, it changes, but still Attributes remains as the blue box (as in figure), when i reopen the properties dialog box. But the default attribute is the blue box itself . Hence I do not find fault with that.

Server :  I am using Wamp Server. (In that MySQL)

And, I have a directory called /tmp.
[image]

Comment: You may need to click the Security tab, click on admin user -> Edit... -> click Full Control checkbox. This should help with solving the issue if you tinker with the permissions from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write the full path for your `/tmp` folder.

I see you're in Windows so this should look like `C:\your_project\tmp`

Comment: ya it worked for me. But why /temp is not worked? It is also a path na. (Though it is a relative path), It refers the same file na.

Answer (score 0):

Start the FTP server of your wamp installation, connect via a ftp client to it, navigate to your /tmp folder and give folder permissions 777 for /tmp and child directories.